# SQL Selecting Records

Tags: sql

I am confused in selecting cars availability from my table as I want to  list all the available Vehicles in a given branch
I have written this query but my brain stuck to carry on !?

```
SELECT MODEL, MAKE, START_DATE, TERMINATION_DATE

FROM VEHICLE_TYPE, VEHICLE, HIRE_AGREEMENT

WHERE VEHICLE_TYPE.VEHICLE_TYPE_ NUN = VEHICLE. VEHICLE_TYPE_NO

AND VEHICLE.VEHICLE_REG_NUM = HIRE_AGREEMENT.VEHICLE_REG_NO
AND ;
```

I believe from the start_date and termination_date I can get cars availability but HOW??

Comment: Please add table structure, example data and expected output. And an [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com) wouldn't hurt too.

Comment: What do you mean "in a given branch"? What is your exact criteria?

Comment: Welcome to the forum.  Please read think link on how to ask questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .  Please show all your table schemas.  What is a "branch" and how does that relate to your query?

Comment: what DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should do a join instead of that old school stuff. Something like this is the best I can suggest given the information you have provided.

```
 SELECT Vehicle.Model, Vehicle.Make, Hire_Agreement.Start_Date,  
  Hire_Agreement.termination_date  FROM Vehicle 
    NATURAL INNER JOIN Hire_Agreement 
     WHERE 
  Hire_agreement.terminationDate >= Date() AND Hire_agreement.start_date <= Date();
```

This is all I can do considering you didnt give us your schema or flavor of SQL.

Comment: Thanks Scotch, your method was brilliant and It worked perfectly, but I had removed the start_date though and instead using Date() I replaced it with SYSDATE  ...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, something like this should work:

```
SELECT MODEL, MAKE, START_DATE, TERMINATION_DATE
FROM VEHICLE_TYPE, VEHICLE, HIRE_AGREEMENT
WHERE VEHICLE_TYPE.VEHICLE_TYPE_ NUN = VEHICLE. VEHICLE_TYPE_NO
AND VEHICLE.VEHICLE_REG_NUM = HIRE_AGREEMENT.VEHICLE_REG_NO
AND GETDATE() BETWEEN VEHICLE.START_DATE AND VEHICLE.TERMINATION_DATE
```

That should return all vehicles available as of the current date